# Rails 6 Active Job “retry_stopped.active_job” subscription is not triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs

I would like to send email with an alert if my Active Job fails the set number of retries but apparently I am doing something wrong subscribing for that event because the action is never triggered. Here is what I got:

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
   queue_as :default
   retry_on MyJobException, wait: 5.minutes, attempts: 3

  ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "retry_stopped.active_job" do |*args|
    ## THIS PART IS NEVER TRIGGERED
    # email the team to let them job still failed after 3 attempts 
    JobMailer.notify_on_job_failure(“MyJob failed despite all retries!”).deliver
  end

  def perform(*args)
    # job tasks
    raise MyJobException if job_failed 
  end
end
```

I couldn’t find any examples on how properly use “retry_stopped.active_job” hook inside code. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks!!!

Comment: Maynot be a solution but - as per sidekiq documentation, when activejobs are used, the callback hooks for deadqueue won't get triggered the same way.  Look at this https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4496#issuecomment-677838552 & https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#customizing-error-handling. Also sidekiq has its own "retries" on top of the worker retry count. so in sidekiq.yml :max_retries: can be kept for a smaller value else the default is 25 which with exponential backoff takes about 25 days. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/sidekiq_style_guide.html